# What are the causes and solutions to battery-powered LCD backlight buzz/hum?

Tags: lcd, sound

Many battery powered devices with LCD displays (eg: clocks or thermostats) will illuminate with a turquoise backlight when a button is pressed. Some of them will emit a buzzing/humming sound while the light is activated.

1. What causes the sound?
2. What can be done (either in design, or for the consumer) to dampen or eliminate the sound?

I'm guessing that the sound is caused by some sort of inverter/charge-pump. [This Link on watch backlights](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/clocks-watches/question296.htm) briefly mentions that low battery voltage must be brought up to something around 200V AC.

Comment: trapped critters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That kind of backlight is an [electroluminescent panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroluminescence). This type of panel requires a fairly high AC voltage to activate it, provided by an inverter.

Such inverters can generate acoustic noise through a variety of mechansims, including magnetostriction in the transformer coil, to piezoelectric effects in capacitors, to transformer windings that are physically loose. The first step would be to determine what the source of the noise is.

Sometimes, what would otherwise be an unnoticeable noise gets amplified to objectionable levels by a resonance in the product's case. This can be addressed by either eliminating the resonance, or decoupling the noise source from the case, typically by incorporating some sort of elastomer (e.g., rubber) into the PCB mounts.